# PHP server --enable-debug side effects

Tags: php, debug

Is it safe to compile php with --enable-debug on a production environment server? Which could be the consequences?

Comment: Slower execution for sure (although I cannot tell how much slower -- on my test box it was around 10% .. but that was almost 2 years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a performance killer, usually what you would want to do is enable debugging on your development environment, do a lot of tests from the user perspective to make sure your application is not going to fail if third-party components are inaccessible.

It is indeed hard to tell how much slower your server will run, it will depend on how many requests you have and what is your hardware.